# Why can't I print the glossary in other part that the end of document

Tags: glossaries

I tried to look for similar question, but none of them seems to have the same issue. I'm using the glossaries package and I followed the tutorials on how to use it (see code). The only different thing is that I want to print the glossary after the table of contents page and not a the very end of the document.

```
% header.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,english]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,top=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,subfigure}

% Abkuerzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries{}
\newglossaryentry{DSL}{name={DSL},description={Domain-Specific Language}}
\newglossaryentry{Bbb}{name={BBB},description={Second abbreviation}}
\newglossaryentry{Ccc}{name={CCC},description={Third abbreviation}}

% Theorem-Umgebungen
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

% Korrekte Darstellung der Umlaute
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

```
% main.tex
\include{header}
\begin{document}

\input{kapitel/frontpage}
\blankpage{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage{}
% Glossary
\printglossary[title=Special Terms, toctitle=List of terms]
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
% Chapters
\setlength{\parskip}{1em plus0.1em minus0.1em}
\input{kapitel/introduction}
\input{kapitel/chapter2}
\input{kapitel/chapter3}
\input{kapitel/chapter4}
\input{kapitel/evaluation}
\input{kapitel/futurework}
\input{kapitel/relatedwork}
\input{kapitel/conclusion}

% Appendix
\appendix
\input{kapitel/appendix}
\clearpage
% list of figures
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\cleardoublepage{}
% list of algorithms
\listofalgorithms{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\cleardoublepage{}
% Literaturverzeichnis
\bibliographystyle{gerplain}
\bibliography{literatur/diplom}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
% Erklaerung
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{}{DECLARATION}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\input{kapitel/declaration}
\cleardoublepage{}
\end{document}
```

the glossary won't show up unless it is placed right before `\end{document}`, can I fix it, so that it'll show up? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here is a more minimal code that still produces the issue: `\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{DSL}{name={DSL},description={Domain-Specific Language}}

\begin{document}
\printglossary
\gls{DSL}

\appendix
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to change `\include{header}` to `\input{header}` as suggested [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9868).
After that minimal change I ran `pdflatex main.tex`, which finally added the line `\@istfilename{main.ist}` into my main.aux file. This line was missing previously and the cmd `makeglossaries main` was giving me an error with the message `No \@istfilename found in 'main.aux'`. Then I ran latter cmd again.. et voilà!